# Why is rotating an image with CGContextDrawImage so much slower than drawing a rotated UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, graphics, uiimage

I'm getting images from the camera and I have to account for them being in different orientations. The first approach I took was to use [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427890/15055) to create a properly-rotated `UIImage`. That calculates a `CGAffineTransform` and then draws the image using `CGContextDrawImage`.

However, this operation took 2-3 seconds to complete.

The second approach I took was to just calculate by how many degrees I'd have to rotate the image, and whether I have to flip it, and then to apply those rotations before drawing the `UIImage`. This approach took a negligible amount of time.

To be specific, I'm using Cocos2D, so in either case I converted the `UIImage` to a `CCTexture2D`, created a sprite with that texture, and then drew it. In the first case, I created a new `UIImage` and had an unrotated `CCSprite`. In the second, I used the same `UIImage` but had a rotated sprite.

Why is the second approach so much faster? The net result is the same: a rotated image. It seems either way the same bits and bytes have to get manipulated in the same way to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [question, experimentation, and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560979/cgcontextdrawimage-is-extremely-slow-after-large-uiimage-drawn-into-it). `UIImage` may be doing some of these optimizations already in the background (Since we don't know the implementation details, there is no real way to know).

Comment: Hmm it can't just be this. When I make a button which, when I press it, rotates the image 90 degrees in Cocos2D, that rotation happens instantly, each time. I can keep hammering on it over and over again, and it looks like no additional memory is being used. It seems like OpenGL does something clever here. I wonder though why the phone can't do that same clever thing in order to rotate the image and get the rotated bytes..